# Why is there no internal flow inside a fluid with stationary interface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

In fluid mechanics, consider a liquid with a free surface denoted by $z=h(x,t)$ (e.g. sessile droplet on a substrate). Suppose the free surface is subject to external forces acting in the normal direction, e.g. we apply an external electric field to a liquid metal so there is an electrostatic stress acting in the normal direction.

Why is there no internal flow inside liquid when the free surface is stationary ($\partial h/\partial t=0$)?

When shear stress is present (e.g. Marangoni effect), there can be internal flow even if $\partial h/\partial t=0$. When shear stress is absent, how to argue rigorously that $\partial h/\partial t=0$ implies zero velocity inside the liquid?